# How to store data in cassandra in a temporary location while sync is in progress?

Tags: cassandra

We have a mysql server running which is serving application writes. To do some batch processing we have written a sync job to migrate data into cassandra cluster.

```
1. A daily sync job which transfers by updated timestamp for that day.
2. A complete sync job which transfers complete data, overriding existing ones.
```

Now there may be a possibility that the row was deleted from mysql, in that case using the above approach it will lie forever in cassandra.

To solve that problem we have given a TTL of 15 days for every row. So eventually it will get deleted, if it was not deleted then in next full sync the TTL will be over written again.

Its working fine as far as the use case is concerned but the issue is that in full sync complete data is over written and sstable is generated continuously with compactions happenning all the time, load averages shoot up with slowness and backup size increases (which could have been avoided).

Essentially we would want to replace the existing table data by new data but we dont want to truncate before starting the job but only after job completes.

Is there any way by which this can be solved other than creating a new table altogether and dropping past table when data is generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the double-run migration strategy I presented here: http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/from-rdbms-to-cassandra-without-a-hitch

It has the advantage of allowing 100% uptime and possible rollback if things go wrong. The downside is the amount of work required in term of releases & codes

Comment: Wow! Its an honor to recieve a comment from the master! Cant wait to use SASI indices in practice :)